# How to import variable (sensor input) & update it from one python script to another?

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, sensors, temperature

I'm currently setting up a some sensors with my raspberry pi in python. Total python newbie here.

Each sensor has it's own script to read the sensor and there is another script that drives an LCD display and displays the imported variable from the sensor script.

I've gotten so far with working scripts that run the sensors and generate output, however, I cannot seem to import the variables (temperature & pH) into the LCD display script. Also, once I have imported the variables, how do I instruct the LCD script to "refresh" the and fetch the updated variable?

Here's a trimmed down version of what I have so far, I've omitted the sensor and data logging parts of each script. For simplicity, script_display is the LCD driver, and pH_script is for pH and temp_script is for temperature.

Here's a simplified version of the scripts:

## script_display.py

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, '/home/pi/Raspberry-Pi-sample-code')
import pH_script
import temp_script
from ph_script import ph_main
from temp_script import get_temp
import time

while True:
        print PH.ph_main(ph_output)
        print get_temp(temp)
        time.sleep(1)
```

## temp_script.py

```
from w1thermsensor import W1ThermSensor
import time

#Get Temperature
def get_temp():
        global temp
        sensor = W1ThermSensor(W1ThermSensor.THERM_SENSOR_DS18B20, "031683a0a4ff")
        activate_temp = sensor.get_temperature()
        temp = str(activate_temp)
        return temp

#Read Temp Frequency
def read():
        threading.Timer(0.5, read).start()
        get_temp()
        time.sleep(1)


  try:
            while True:
                    read()
                    get_temp()
                    print get_temp()
  except KeyboardInterrupt:               
        print("Program Ended By User")
```

## pH_script.py

```
def ph_main():
```

*lots and lots of code to activate the PH probe, and other variables, but the variable ph_output returns as a string, ph_output*

```
    try:
        while True:

                  global ph_output
                  dev.send_cmd("R")
                  lines = dev.read_lines()
                  for i in range(len(lines)):
                                print lines[i]
                                if lines[i][0] != '*':
                                         print lines[i]
                                         ph_output = str(lines[i])
                                         return ph_output
                                         time.sleep(delaytime)
try:
        while True:
                ph_main() 

   except KeyboardInterrupt:               
                print("Continuous polling stopped")
```

so, again, first question, how to pass the global variables back to the display script? and two, how to instruct the display script to 'refresh' the variables?

the error I am currently getting is:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "script_display.py", line 8, in <module>
    print PH.ph_main(ph_output)
NameError: name 'ph_output' is not defined
```

looking forward to any input and thanks for your time + help!

Comment: Neither `ph_main()` nor `get_temp()` are defined to take a parameter, so why are you trying to pass one?

Comment: Hi Jason, thanks for your input - i've been taking a look at other examples of how other scripts are setup to read the sensors and there are no arguments / parameters there either. I just want to pass the sensor readings from one script to another, without manipulating the readings.

Comment: Right, so just call the imported function with no parameter.  You're getting that error because the parameter that you didn't need to pass is something that doesn't even exist.